# Which one is correct in my case?

Tags: past-tense

Which sentence in below is correct grammatically? In my case the event take place at past, and now i'm telling this to someone ...

"I became so immersed that i completely lost track of time. "  or 
"I become so immersed that i completely lost track of time."

Comment: If you became, then you lost. If you become, then you lose. But not just a random mix of the two. Pick your narrative and stick to it.

Comment: Think logically about the second option and you’ll see why it won’t work: you _become_ (now, in the present) so immersed that you _lost_ (then, in the past) track of time. How can becoming immersed now be the cause of you losing track of time in the past? That’s kind of like saying that someone gets hit by a car today, and as a result they died yesterday.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi AA360c, you may not be aware that this EL&U site is for "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts", whereas your question is probably more suited to our other site [ell.se]. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think " I became so immersed that I completely lost track of time." is the right one because as you said it happened in the past.